# I need to create a filter on Matlab according to: H(z) = (-z^(-2)-2*z^(-1)+2*z+z^2)/8T. Which are the coefficiants a and b?

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing

I have to filter a signal with a filter which has a Transfer Function:

`H(z) = (-z^(-2)-2*z^(-1)+2*z+z^2)/8T`, where `T=1/fc`.

What are the a and b coefficient?

I don't understand if a is `[8*T]` or `[1,8*T]`.

I really don't know what to do.